# AES Key Generation from variables

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I want to code a custom key generator in Python. This key will be used as an input (along with the plain text) to AES algorithm for encryption (I will probably use `pycrypto` or `m2crypto` libraries for that).

But the key generator has to be custom, as it would generate the key based on the string that would be supplied by the user.

```
str = date + case-id + name

where:
date = current date when a case was submitted 
(we work on separate security analysis cases, submitted on our ticketing tool)
name = person handling the case
case-id = the ticket id with which it was submitted.
```

This same key needs to be known to the decryptor (on a different system) so that it can decrypt the data.

So the key will have to be fixed for a specific set of `date` `name` and `case-id` for a specific order and will only be different if any of these 3 change in `value` or `order` and should not be random every time.

I've gone through some of stackoverflow articles, where it is suggested to use

```
random_key = os.urandom(16)
```

but I don't believe this will serve my purpose.

Suggestion on some articles where to start with if I want to design a key generator from scratch, or some pointers on existing libraries will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a [Password hashing](https://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/) algorithm, such as Argon2 or PBKDF2. It will allow you to deterministically extend the 'password' generated from the input values into a suitable key.

**However**, note that your passwords may still be very weak. I suspect that there is a strong correlation between case-id and date. Names are probably only a small list of people easily found out. Also, isn't this data sent along with the encrypted data by your system? This makes using it as a password a **bad idea**.